# solving this second order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second order ODE where

$
(k-x)^2 y''+6(k-x)y'+12y=F(x)
$

where $k$ is some constant.
I want to compute the real valued general solution.

progress: guess $(k-x)^{m}$ to be the solution and I find m
to be of the form $m=a+bi$.
Applying variation of parameters,
it takes me into a long algebra mess.

Any trick/ways to do this quickly.
($y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are given.)

Comment: Is the ODE supposed to be $(k - x)^2 y'' + 6(k-x) y' + 12y = F(x)$?  If so, you should be guessing $(k-x)^m$ as the form of the solution, since $y$ is the function to be solved. If the equation you've written is supposed to be correct, then the equation is nonlinear and variation of parameters does not apply.

Comment: thanks, I meant what you said above and I have edited my question now.

Comment: What is $F(x)$?

Comment: $F(x)=(1-c)(x-k)^2+6(x-k)-24$.

Answer (score 2):

First, solve the homogeneous differential equation which is of [Euler differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html) type and has a solution

$$ y \left( x \right) ={c_1}\, \left( x-k \right) ^{3}+{c_2}\,
 \left( x-k \right) ^{4}.$$

So, the fundamental set of solutions is given by $ \left\{ \left( x-k \right) ^{3},\left( x-k \right) ^{4} \right\}. $

You can see that the solutions are linearly independent, since the Wronskian is $-(k-x)^6$. Now just advance with the [method of variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to find the particular solution.

Comment: Thanks Mhenni,I guessed the solution to be of the form $(x-k)^{m}$ and when I solved for the char.roots, I did it wrong  and got $m$ to be a complex number and went to a wrong route when I used the VOP.

Comment: @abiyo: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If that is not cheating, you could try a computer algebra package, like [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/). At least to help with the "algebra mess" you mention.