# Solution to second order differential equation with log

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can you find a solution to $y''+\alpha^2y=\log(x)$ on $(0,1]$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ ?Preferably not expressed in terms of series because I know how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried [variation of parameters technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to find a particular solution?

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285274/solving-this-second-order-ode). Note that, your solution will involve some special functions.